# Entity Framework Code First CTP5 : How to define non primitive types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-ctp5

I'm testing the CTP5 for entity framwork code first, and i've run into this problem
I've got a class that has a property of type Uri (System.Uri), but it looks like it's unable to automatically identify how to store that, so i get an error like

```
Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 23:No mapping specified for properties WebPage.Uri in Set WebPage
```

How can i tell the model to map the Uri to a varchar, for example, with the url of the uri??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual POCO model has to bind to primitive types.  You can use a complex type binding such as:

```
[ComplexType()]
public class UriHelper
{
    public string StringRepresentation {get;set;}
    public Uri ActualUri()
    {
        return new Uri(StringRepresentation);
    }
}
```

And in your actual object reference this complex type as the Uri reference if you absolutely need to.  Your mapping would then reference the property for the actual value as a String.  The final option is to create a custom mapping from URI to string and vice versa for the EF engine to use.  However, I would not advise this.  The actual database property is of type varchar or nvarchar, not URI.  Thus EF doesn't know what a URI is.